# bxslider only working on vertical scroll, not horizontal

Tags: jquery, bxslider, sliders

I'm trying to implement a bxslider on a website sidebar but for some reason it is only working when I set the mode to "vertical" when I set the mode to "horizontal," which should be the default, or put nothing at all for mode, the slider transitions do not work. I'm trying to accomplish a slider showing 1 slide at a time and auto transitioning to the next slide but even with the vertical scroll working I still have to manually hit a pager to get to the next slide. I'm kind've stumped on the problem.

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/wp-content/themes/axon-responsive/images/slide1.png" />
            <br>
            <quote>“Axon Radiology was reliable and timely with great response on any questions or issues.”</quote>
            <hr>
            <p>Brandon Selle</p>
            <span>Northeast Missouri Imaging Associates</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/wp-content/themes/axon-responsive/images/slide2.png" />
            <quote>“We changed radiology groups due to inaccurate reads from our previous vendor. We are extremely happy with Axon Radiology and the quality of service they are providing for our company. I believe Axon Radiology takes pride in the performance of their radiologists. We get speedy turnaround and excellent reporting from this company.”
                </p>
                <hr>
                <p>Theresa Summers</p>
                <span>Georgia Emergency Associates</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/wp-content/themes/axon-responsive/images/slide3.png" />
            <quote>“Our prior teleradiology services had long wait times for the reports, even after calling and stating the patient was a priority patient. For one service the reports were not accurate in addition to the extended wait time. Axon Radiology is dependable, accurate and provides fast report turnaround times. We are very pleased with the services provided and are happy to recommend you to others."</quote>
            <hr>
            <p>Tammy Cullen</p>
            <span>Cypress Creek ER</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/wp-content/themes/axon-responsive/images/slide4.png" />
            <quote>“Excellent service with results we can trust.”</quote>
            <hr>
            <p>Yadira Sanchez</p>
            <span>Saddleback Family & Urgent Care Medical Group</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/wp-content/themes/axon-responsive/images/slide2.png" />
            <quote>“Axon helps us achieve this goal by providing over reads in as little as 20 minutes. Our previous provider was unable to do this. We are very happy with the service provided by Axon Radiology. It is easy and the staff are very helpful and easy to work with. Every time that I have reached out for help or more information about an interface, etc. I have received support and guidance. I appreciate the effort Axon puts into helping their customers grow.”</quote>
            <hr>
            <p>Lisa Horton</p>
            <span>Georgia Emergency Associates</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        slideWidth: 240,
        minSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 10,
        controls: 'false',
        pager: 'true',
        moveSlides: '1',
        autoStart: 'true',
        auto: true;
 });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. It was a css error where I was giving the bxslider a max width.